# Overriding ToString with a custom data type

Tags: c#, tostring, custom-data-type

In main I have the following code:

```cs
var json = new JValue { Object = new Dictionary<string, JValue>() };
json["name"] = new JValue("Lebron James");
json["age"] = new JValue(23);

if (json.Type == JType.Object)
{
    foreach (var value in json.Object)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(value.ToString());
    }
}
```

The custom class and data type are the following:

```
public enum JType
{
    Null,
    Bool,
    Number,
    String,
    Array,
    Object,
}

public class JValue
{
    public JType Type { get; private set; }
    private JsonValue Value { get; set; }

    public JValue()
    {
        Type = JType.Null;
    }

    public JValue(bool value)
    {
        Type = JType.Bool;
        Value = new JsonBool { Value = value };
    }

    public JValue(double value)
    {
        Type = JType.Number;
        Value = new JsonNumber { Value = value };
    }

    public JValue(string value)
    {
        Type = JType.String;
        Value = new JsonString { Value = value };
    }

    public JValue(List<JValue> values)
    {
        Type = JType.Array;
        Value = new JsonArray { Values = values };
    }

    public JValue(Dictionary<string, JValue> values)
    {
        Type = JType.Object;
        Value = new JsonObject { Values = values };
    }

    public bool Null
    {
        get { return Type == JType.Null; }
        set { Type = JType.Null; Value = null; }
    }

    public bool Bool
    {
        get
        {
            if (Type != JType.Bool) throw new InvalidCastException();
            return ((JsonBool)Value).Value;
        }
        set
        {
            Type = JType.Bool;
            Value = new JsonBool { Value = value };
        }
    }

    public double Number
    {
        get
        {
            if (Type != JType.Number) throw new InvalidCastException();
            return ((JsonNumber)Value).Value;
        }
        set
        {
            Type = JType.Number;
            Value = new JsonNumber { Value = value };
        }
    }

    public string String
    {
        get
        {
            if (Type != JType.String) throw new InvalidCastException();
            return ((JsonString)Value).Value;
        }
    }

    public List<JValue> Array
    {
        get
        {
            if (Type != JType.Array) throw new InvalidCastException();
            return ((JsonArray)Value).Values;
        }
        set
        {
            Type = JType.Array;
            Value = new JsonArray { Values = value };
        }
    }

    public Dictionary<string, JValue> Object
    {
        get
        {
            if (Type != JType.Object) throw new InvalidCastException();
            return ((JsonObject)Value).Values;
        }
        set
        {
            Type = JType.Object;
            Value = new JsonObject { Values = value };
        }
    }

    public JValue this[string key]
    {
        get { return Object[key]; }
        set { Object[key] = value; }
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get { return Array.Count; }
    }

    public JValue this[int index]
    {
        get { return Array[index]; }
        set { Array[index] = value; }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Value.ToString();
    }
}

internal class JsonValue
{
}

internal class JsonBool : JsonValue
{
    public bool Value;
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Value.ToString();
    }
}

internal class JsonNumber : JsonValue
{
    public double Value;
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Value.ToString();
    }
}

internal class JsonString : JsonValue
{
    public string Value;
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Value.ToString();
    }
}

internal class JsonArray : JsonValue
{
    public List<JValue> Values;
}

internal class JsonObject : JsonValue
{
    public Dictionary<string, JValue> Values;
}
```

I've attempted to override ToString() with this function but it's not giving me the value.

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return Value.ToString();
}
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the output you're expecting to see?

Comment: I'm trying to output just the value itself.

Answer (score 2):

You have to override `ToString()` method in each class derived from `JsonValue` because `JValue.ToString()` calls the `JsonValue.ToString()` method which is not overridden so that it will display the full name of the class.

Additionally I suggest replacing the public fields to public auto-properties.

So for example:

```cs
internal class JsonBool : JsonValue
{
    public bool Value { get; set; }

    public string override ToString()
    {
        return Value.ToString();
    }
}
```

UPDATE #1:

A better solution would be to introduce a generic type so that you can avoid the tons of ToString() override.

```cs
internal class JsonValue<T>
{
    public T Value { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Value.ToString();
    }
}

internal class JsonBool : JsonValue<bool>
{
}

internal class JsonDouble : JsonValue<double>
{
}
```

Comment: That works for initialized a string like: var person = new JValue("Lebron");

Comment: When I try to display the values for Dictionary and Arrays I get something like this: System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,oop_hw.JValue]. I'm assuming I need a for each loop in the dictionary and array classes but I'm not sure how to construct it.

Answer (score 0):

Gabor's answer is correct, that you need to override `ToString` on the `JsonValue` derived objects.  His other advice about the generics and replacing the fields with properties is also good.

For your array and object types, you'll need to loop over the values contained in those types.  You may need to play around with the code to get the output to come out the way you want it to.

Note that the code below doesn't take into account nested items.  For example, if your `JsonObject` was holding a `JValue` that was *also* a `JsonObject` holding more values.

```
internal class JsonArray : JsonValue
{
    public List<JValue> Values;
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Join(", ", Values ?? Enumerable.Empty<JValue>());
    }
}

internal class JsonObject : JsonValue
{
    public Dictionary<string, JValue> Values;
    public override string ToString()
    {
        if (Values == null || Values.Count <= 0)
        {
            return "";
        }

        var builder = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var item in Values)
        {
            builder
                .AppendFormat("{0}: {1}", item.Key, item.Value)
                .AppendLine();
        }

        return builder.ToString();
    }
}
```